# Split regex matches with end of line or character

Tags: regex

I have the following string i want to extract data from :

```
foo from 01/05/1964 to 31/03/1965 - bar from 01/09/1966 to 30/09/1966
foobar from 01/09/1967 to 30/09/1967
```

I tried many regex expressions, using the lazy operator or not, and i can't find an expression that splits the first line.

```
(.*) from (.*) to (.*)    
(?:(.*) from (.*) to (.*))[-$]??
(.*)?? from (.*) to (.*)
(.*?) from (.*?) to (.*?)[-$]
```

I have the feeling it's a very simple solution...

The following works, but I don't want to specify a format for the dates, in case it changes

```
(?: - )?(.*?) from (.{10}) to (.{10})
```

Comment: Try `(\w+)\s+from\s+([\d\/.-]+)\s+to\s+([\d\/.-]+)` - see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mKzQf9/2).

Comment: Or, `(?:\s-\s|^)(.*?)\s+from\s+(\d+\W\d+\W\d+)\s+to\s+(\d+\W\d+\W\d+)` - see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/mKzQf9/3/).

Comment: Did anything help?

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
(?:(.*) from (.*) to (.*)(?\s*-\s*)?)+
```

Comment: could you write a sentence explaining your solution, how does it improve what the OP tried